# Preventing the entered key to be appended to an input field value

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a form and a Text Input field that will be used to display dates.  I want to be able capture entries via `.onkeypress` so that <kbd>+</kbd> adds a day, <kbd>-</kbd> subtracts a day, etc.

I have everything working except that the key that I enter (in the example below the <kbd>+</kbd> key) ends up being appended to the `dDate` field as well.

The moment.js is added in a `<script>` tag in the HTML `<head>` tag
Below would be found after the HTML `<body>` tag

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="dDate" size="25" value="11/22/2014"></textarea>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("dDate").onkeypress=function(e) {
    var e=window.event || e
    var keyunicode=e.charCode || e.keyCode
    //Allow alphabetical keys, plus BACKSPACE and SPACE
    // return (keyunicode>=65 && keyunicode<=122 || keyunicode==8 || keyunicode==32)? true : false
    switch (keyunicode) {
        case 61:
            alert("Hit Plus Key: "+ keyunicode);
            break ;
        case 43:
            var cDate = document.getElementById("dDate");
            var d = moment(cDate.value);
            var duration = moment.duration({'days' : 1});
            d.add(duration);
            cNewDate = d.format('MM/DD/YYYY')
            cDate.value = cNewDate;
            break;
        case 187:
            alert("Hit Plus Key: "+ keyunicode);
            break;
        default:
            alert("Hit non-Plus Key" + keyunicode);
    }
}
</script>
```

Below would be standard HTML `</body>` tag

The result of the above if you hit the <kbd>+</kbd> key is the `dDate` field is incremented to 11/23/2014, but also has the "+", resulting in: `11/23/2014+`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `e.preventDefault()` at the at the end of your script will fix your issue.

```
document.getElementById("dDate").onkeypress = function(e) {
    // ...
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

Additionally, `<input>` is self-closing so that `</textarea>` needs to be removed.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the very fast response.
I added that line just before the last "}" of the function, but while it no longer prevents me from repeating the "+" key to add additional days to the date, it still adds the "+" key at the end of the field.
Any other thoughts?

Comment: @KevinHunt I noticed you have a `</textarea>` after your input, make sure to remove that. I also setup a working fiddle, without moment, but working as intended nonetheless: http://jsfiddle.net/6ueupu0f/